# Apply to jobs on external sites using developer story

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-deferred, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I don't know if this is the right place to ask/suggest but...

I am moderately active on SO (visit it 3-5 times/week or so). And I keep my dev profile updated (more or less). I am not looking for a new job but from time to time SO provides some interesting matches, that I wouldn't mind checking out and learning some details.

The annoying part is that each time I click apply I get to the company normal apply page and have to fill out all my info again (rather normal since company is unrelated to SO, but the job was added on SO, the match was made by SO).

Wouldn't be nice to have a quick apply button somewhere that would just send the dev story to the company (a simple mail or something)? In 90% of the cases all the data required is already in there. That would actually let ppl that are not actively looking (I know at least 10 ppl that are in same situation) to quickly apply to interesting positions.

PROS:

- Saves time for candidates
- Ppl are generally reticent on creating profiles on sites they are not accustomed to (using the dev story instead of creating a profile somewhere would help with that - although is kind of the same)
- Can do it from phone on subway (is really a pain filling data from phones)

CONS:

- Some companies have a "mini interview" on the page (2-3 questions that in most cases are useless imo), that would not be satisfied by dev story alone; but here solutions can be found (but is another topic)
- Some companies may ignore profiles sent like that

Anyway... that's about it. If feature already exists (I'm pretty sure I'm not the first guy that felt the need for this) maybe hint me how to use it? :)

Comment: _I don't know if this is the right place to ask/suggest but..._ yeah this is the right place.. But your query seems to be about a bigger (problem ?) that most companies want appliers to create accounts and fill data even if you apply with any job portal profile/resume...

Comment: For jobs using our internal application process (i.e. it takes you to a page on Stack Overflow to apply) we already support applying with your developer story and we pre-fill most of the fields so it's mostly just click apply then click confirm. Sadly external applications are outside of our control

Comment: @DeanWard So there is an internal application process? Sadly I never seen it :(. Does this mean that companies have an option to set the way candidates apply to their jobs and the ones I tried didn't use it? Or I need to activate some option somewhere to use it?

Comment: @zozo some companies have their application processes in other systems. Whilst we try to integrate with as many as we can sometimes the only option is for them to point the application at an external system. [Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/169630/digital-developer-c-sharp-angular-junior-to-lead-newday-ltd) of a job that uses our internal application process. It's quite common so surprised that you haven't come across it...

Comment: I checked your example... cool... that's the thing I wanted. Never seen it in action at things I checked out though. Ty.

Comment: @zozo - usually thats a sign of a bad company who uses some conglomerate job hosting site that captures resumes and makes everything so complex.  These companies usually stress year after year that they are losing so much money and looking to cut costs but they pay tens of thousands of dollars for said systems.  Sad...

Comment: @JonH I try not to judge and give them the benefit of a doubt. Still because I'm not actually looking, having to fill tens of fields for applying... nope... I just don't apply :).

Answer (score 2):

This is something we've heard before - filling out application forms offsite can be a pain and your suggestion here might be a great alternative. We'll have to do a some research on our end with employers to understand how they might integrate this into their workflow. As Dean mentioned, we prefer to integrate their application form directly on our site and we support this functionality for some of the larger applicant tracking systems that our customers use. But there are many customers who use systems we don't support and using our standing apply form breaks their internal workflow.

I'm setting this as [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) only because it's not currently scheduled. Time saving features to help with job searching is however something we are interested in.